# How to make this message multilingual in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I made a payment method moudle in drupal.i use
`drupal_set_message(t('An error occurred and processing did not complete.'), 'error');` 
Can I make this message multilingual in my moudle?

Comment: One small comment, drupal_set_message is depreciated function. Instead of this use \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface::addMessage().  
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/8.9.x   
If you can't see your translated string in UI, try to clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

When using this tag ‍‍`t`, you can translate the text of original language into other languages with config->regional->translate.